# python not creating file in mode x

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6

well I have done this

```
    try:
        with open('add/report.txt', 'x')as f:
            pass
    except FileExistsError:
        pass
    finally:
        with open('add/report.txt', 'a')as f:
            f.write(message)
            f.write('-------------------')
```

and I get error `FileNotFoundError` even after I tried to open the file in `x mode` to create it first

Comment: Cannot reproduce the error. The code worked perfectly fine.

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'add/report.txt'
this is what I get and I don't understand why,
that is why I am asking here what is the problem

Comment: Does the directory `add` exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to make a file into a folder that does not exist.

Here is a working example with automatic file and folder creation:

```
from pathlib import Path

def send(message):

    target_file = r'c:\tmp\path\which\does\not\exist\report.txt'

    p = Path(target_file)
    if not p.exists():
        p.parent.mkdir(parents=True)


    with open(p, 'a')as f:
        f.write(message)
        f.write('-------------------')
```